# Trying to add HTML node but it doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

I've got the following javascript function:

```
    function addConfirmLine(number, strItem, strValue) {
        var confirmLine = document.getElementById("divConfirmation").appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        confirmLine.id = "divConfirmLine" + number;

        var confirmItem = confirmLine.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        confirmItem.className = "confirmItem";
        confirmItem.nodeValue = strItem;

        var confirmValue = confirmLine.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
        confirmValue.className = "confirmValue";
        confirmValue.nodeValue = strValue;
    }
```

and a `div` like this

```
<div id="divConfirmation">
    <div class="checkHead">
        Check the following details.  Click "Prev" to make corrections.  Click "Upload" to process and upload the sermon.
    </div>
</div>
```

The intent is to end up with something like this:

```
<div id="divConfirmation">
    <div class="checkHead">
        Check the following details.  Click "Prev" to make corrections.  Click "Upload" to process and upload the sermon.
    </div>
    <div id="divConfirmLine1">
        <div class="confirmItem">Item1</div>
        <div class="confirmValue">Value1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="divConfirmLine2">
        <div class="confirmItem">Item2</div>
        <div class="confirmValue">Value2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is it doesn't work.  The new `div`s don't appear, and I don't get any errors.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which browsers have you tested in?  Does it work on any or none?

Comment: It's in an HTA running in IE8

Comment: Just tried it in Firefox as an .htm with the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodeValue of an Element is always null. You want to add text nodes:

```
confirmItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(strItem));
confirmValue.appendChild(document.createTextNode(strValue));
```